# How to export a dataframe to a list of cell and not a list of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

Not sure how else to ask this question, but this is just a very specific type of transform that I need to perform on an extremely large dataset so it has to be as efficient as possible.

Let's say my dataframe looks like this:

| id | 1/01/2001 | 1/02/2001 | 1/03/2001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 629 | 138 | 240 |
| 2 | 249 | 480 | 104 |
| 3 | 264 | 246 | 244 |
| 4 | 259 | 842 | 278 |

So I'm tracking the values of each id over time in a column, but I need to transform it into an array of dictionaries. Typically I could just use `df.to_dict('records')` because because of the shape, I have to get a little more clever. I want the array of dictionaries to look like this:

```
[
  {
     'id': 1,
     '1/01/2001': 629
  },
  {
     'id': 1,
     '1/02/2001': 138
  },
  {
     'id': 1,
     '1/03/2001': 240
  },
  {
     'id': 2,
     '1/01/2001': 249
  },
  {
     'id': 2,
     '1/02/2001': 480
  },
  {
     'id': 2,
     '1/03/2001': 104
  },
  ...
]
```

And so on...

Is there a simple way of doing this without using a convoluted for loop?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. How is this not just df.to_dict(records)?

Comment: @ifly6 'records make `[{'id': 1, '1/01/2001': 629, '1/02/2001': 138, '1/03/2001': 240}, {'id': 2, '1/01/2001': 249, '1/02/2001': 480, '1/03/2001': 104}` by rows, he want by cell

Comment: @ifly6 it would be `df.to_dict('records')` if the dataframe's columns were `id, date, value`, but the values are being tracked in the columns so it's kinda weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest seem to be with `id` as index, and 2 loops, as I found nothing about exporting a DF to a list of cells

```
result = [{'id': i, k: v} for i, cols in df.to_dict('index').items() 
                          for k, v in cols.items()]
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed, very clever